# Unattended install of opam package manager

Tags: continuous-integration, ocaml, opam

What's the usual way to install the latest version of OPAM (the OCaml package manager) in a CI environment (e.g. Travis CI)? The official [install.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh) shell script prompts for user input and doesn't have any command line options or environment variables to override that. I could use `echo` or `cat` to pipe some replies to standard input but that seems quite brittle.

I could also install OPAM from the OS package manager (e.g. apt on Linux) but it's often not the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to use the scripts in [ocaml-ci-scripts](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-ci-scripts). The travis integration is [documented here](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-ci-scripts/blob/master/README-travis.md).